# react cannot find file-saver although it was installed

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, file-saver

React don't see 'file-saver' although it was installed.

I made `yarn add file-saver`, then `yarn install` and still nothing.

It's imported like :
`import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';`

in package.json looks like:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@emotion/is-prop-valid": "^1.1.0",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.2",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
        "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.48",
        "@mui/material": "^5.0.1",
        "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.3",
        "@types/react-table": "^7.7.2",
        "axios": "0.21.1",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "date-fns": "^2.24.0",
        "document-register-element": "1.13.1",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding also "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5", apart of "file-saver": "^2.0.5"